# Fourier Series of a given function

Tags: python, performance, numpy, signal-processing, scipy

This is a very simple code that expresses a function in terms of Trigonometric Fourier Series and generates a animation based on the harmonics. I would like to know some ways to improve the performance of the code and its readability. I believe that any question about the mathematical part can be answered [here](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/fourier-series.html).

Here's the whole code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import sin, cos, pi, linspace
from scipy.integrate import quad as integral
from celluloid import Camera


def desired_function(t):
    return t**2


def a_zero(function, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit):
    return (1/(2*half_period)) * integral(function, inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]


def a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit):
    return (1/half_period) * integral(lambda x: desired_function(x) * cos(x * k * (pi / half_period)), inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]


def b_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit):
    return (1/half_period) * integral(lambda x: desired_function(x) * sin(x * k * (pi / half_period)), inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]


def main():
    fig = plt.figure()
    camera = Camera(fig)

    inferior_limit, superior_limit = -pi, pi
    half_period = (superior_limit - inferior_limit) / 2
    x = linspace(inferior_limit, superior_limit, 1000)

    f = a_zero(desired_function, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)

    # The sum ranging from 1 to total_k
    total_k = 30
    for k in range(1, total_k+1):
        f += a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*cos(k*x*(pi/half_period)) +\
             b_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*sin(k*x*(pi/half_period))

        plt.plot(x, desired_function(x), color='k')
        plt.plot(x, f, label=f'k = {k}')
        camera.snap()

    animation = camera.animate()
    plt.close()
    animation.save('animation.gif')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my biggest issue is this for loop being used as a Σ, is there a more elegant way to express this?

```
# The sum ranging from 1 to total_k
    total_k = 30
    for k in range(1, total_k+1):
        f += a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*cos(k*x*(pi/half_period)) +\
             b_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*sin(k*x*(pi/half_period))
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes the time to help me with this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like it.
This code hews closely to the underlying math,
using lovely identifiers, and is very clear.

---

For {a,b}_k, here's the only
part I'm not super happy with:

```
def a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit):
    return (1/half_period) * integral(lambda x: desired_function(x) * cos(x * k * (pi / half_period)), inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]
```

We went with `desired_function` as a global.
Ok, not the end of the world.
Just sayin', consider adding it to the parameters.

I probably would have gone with a concise `lo, hi`
instead of `inferior_limit, superior_limit`.
But hey, that's just me, it's a matter of taste.
Don't change it on my account, looks good as it is.
Maybe package them both as the 2-tuple `limits`,
and then the call goes from

```
    ... * integral(... * (pi / half_period)), inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]
```

to

```
    ... * integral(... * (pi / half_period)), *limits)[0]
```

---

```
def main():
    ...
    x = linspace(inferior_limit, superior_limit, 1000)
    ...
    total_k = 30
```

We have two
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)),
both quite reasonable.

Consider burying one or both of them in the signature:

```
def main(num_points=1000, total_k=30):
```

One benefit of such practice is it makes it easy
for unit tests to adjust numbers to more convenient values.

---

It wouldn't hurt to sometimes add a """docstring"""
to a function, explaining what it expects and
what it offers. Not *every* function, mind you,
just the big one(s).

---

To follow
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008)
conventions more closely, consider running
[black](https://pypi.org/project/black)
over this source.
Whitespace within math expressions
tends to improve readability.

---

> more elegant way to express [the summation?]

No, I respectfully disagree with your assessment.
It exactly corresponds to the math and it looks beautiful to me.
You could change it, but then I fear it would be less clear.

Now, if we wanted to worry about efficiency and execution
speed, there are some constants that could be
[hoisted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)
out of the loop,
and the repeated calls to `integral()` seem like
they might show up on
[cProfile's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
hit list. But if we cared about elapsed time
we would use numba's `@jit` or another technique,
and compilers are good at hoisting.
This code achieves its design goals and is maintainable.
ATM it looks good to me.

Ship it!

Answer (score 1):

You have really clean code, I can only suggest a few improvements:

The functions `a_k` and `b_k` have a quite long line, I suggest using a named function rather than a lambda like this:

```
def a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit):
    def integrand(x):
        return desired_function(x) * cos(x * k * (pi / half_period))
    return (1/half_period) * integral(integrand, inferior_limit, superior_limit)[0]
```

In this way you have shorter line of code and a self-documenting name following standard mathematical conventions for the [integrand](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Integrand.html)

The same for `b_k`.

---

Regarding the summmation in the loop I would rewrite it from:

```
total_k = 30
for k in range(1, total_k+1):
    f += a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*cos(k*x*(pi/half_period)) +\
         b_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*sin(k*x*(pi/half_period))
```

To:

```
total_k = 30
for k in range(1, total_k+1):
    trig_argument = k*x*(pi/half_period)
    cosine_contribution = a_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*cos(trig_argument)
    sine_contribution   = b_k(k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)*sin(trig_argument)
    f += cosine_contribution + sine_contribution
```

To add descriptive names to variables and highlight that sine and cosine are called with the same argument, but at the cost of being a bit longer. Anyhow also your version is fine. Another possibility is `integration_arguments = (k, half_period, inferior_limit, superior_limit)` and using it later, to highlight that the integration is over the same bounds for sine and cosine, this would also highlight the similarity of the operations for sine and cosine.